# SQLite calls the same INSERT command twice

Tags: android, android-sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I was trying to insert multiple data based on two arrays. Both contains different value. And I want to insert them into one same table.

In my DBHandler I wrote INSERT statement as below

```
public void addData(Foto foto) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TGL, foto.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_SITEID, foto.getSiteid());
    values.put(KEY_KATEGORI, foto.getKategori());
    values.put(KEY_FILENAME, foto.getFilename());
    values.put(KEY_PATH, foto.getPath());

    db.insert(TABLE_SHOPS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

And in my activity. I wrote like this

```
for(int i=0;i<=namefile.length;i++){
            Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[namefile.length];
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(namefile[i]));
            bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString[i],0,decodedString[i].length);
            bitmap[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), namefile[i].getAbsolutePath(), namefile[i].getName(), namefile[i].getName());

            db.addData(new Foto(fDate,siteid,"genset_progres",namefile[i].getName(),namefile[i].getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        for(int a=0;a<=var.length;a++){
            db.addData(new Foto(fDate,siteid,"genset_progres","",var[a]));
        }
```

I intended to insert the data of `namefile` and the data of `var` into same table. So I wrote like above...But when I call them only namefile got inserted into database. I'm sorry I'm not quite understand about how looping and SQLITE works on android since this is my first time trying it. Maybe u guys can help me. I'd appreciate it a lot.

If there's anything I should provide...dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: Only one row from `namefile` is inserted?

Comment: more than one row

Comment: Try removing this line `db.close()` from the `addData` method and put it after the loops, when both are finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
for(int i=0;i<=namefile.length;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<namefile.length;i++)
```

and also

```
for(int a=0;a<=var.length;a++)
```

to

```
for(int a=0;a<var.length;a++)
```

so that you could run the code without ArrayOutOfBoundsException.